# Side Effects of Monitoring Blood Stream for Weeks?

Tags: hematology

Is there currently some safe method to monitor arterial blood for weeks while "living normally"? Essentially, do doctors monitor some people's bloods contents by attaching some device that constantly draws and analyzes blood?

What is it, what are the risks? What are the side effects of this device? Where is it usually attached?

If not, why not, what's keeping this from existing?

Comment: What are you trying to monitor? Some implantable glucose monitors can do this, though I can't say whether it's "arterial" blood. Is capillary blood good enough?

Comment: Testosterone //comment length

Comment: Then no. There is no reason to monitor testosterone continuously; it's not life threatening (as is hypoglycemia.) No sane businessman would devote the funds to develop and test such a device, and the risk of side effects (mainly infection) and cost of placement/upkeep/etc much too high for basically no additional return over drawn blood.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I can think of one example that would potentially be useful and worth the risks: monitoring potassium levels in people with hypokalemic periodic paralysis. Wouldn't need to be arterial blood, though.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I was specifically addressing the OP's concern. Even with HPP, I doubt a manufacturer would be willing to invest at this point; the number of people with the disorder  are orders of magnitude fewer than diabetics. In all my years of practice, I've seen **one** case of HPP. Diabetics? Many hundreds at least.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Oh, I completely agree. The market just isn't there. I was simply pointing it out as the only example I can think of that might actually be useful to someone.